# Utilize unused hard drive space

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, sd-card

I have a MK802 Mini PC with a nice 16gb SD card running Rikomagic Linux; however, I can't even tap into more than 3.7gb of it. The system image (.IMG) I installed on the SD card was ~7.8gb.

"fdisk -l" reveals we do indeed have unused or unmounted space:

```
Disk /dev/nandi: 2252 MB, 2252341248 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 273 cylinders, total 4399104 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 15.9 GB, 15931539456 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 486192 cylinders, total 31116288 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8daf8ee2

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1            2048       34815       16384   83  Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p2           34816     7858175     3911680   83  Linux
```

It appears to me most of the storage is in /dev/mmcblk0p2; if possible, how would I make this usable to my system, by expanding mmcblk0p2 into unused space or adding unused space to /mnt/?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what OS you are running. According to the Rikomagic website, the MK802 runs Android. Is that what you mean by Rikomagic Linux or have you installed an actual Linux distribution on the machine?

If you *are* running a proper Linux, you should be able to just mount the partition. Try the following (as root):

1. Create the mountpoint

   ```
   mkdir /mnt/data
   ```
2. Mount the device

   ```
   mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /mnt/data
   ```

If that works, you can make it permanent by adding this line to your `/etc/fstab` (assuming the partition is formatted as ext4, if not, change accordingly):

```
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /mnt/data   ext4    defaults    0   0
```